# Why does list property in python take all values of all objects in list of objects?

Tags: python

I created a class in python, and this class has one property that is a list. Then I tried to instantiate a list of those objects, but when i try to append a new member to that property of object all list of all objects get value appended. I am new at python, can somebody try to explain where is the mistake in my code?

```
class NewClass():
    classList=[]



listObjects=[]


listObjects.append(NewClass())
listObjects.append(NewClass())
listObjects.append(NewClass())
listObjects.append(NewClass())


for i in range(0,4):
    listObjects[i].classList.append(i)

for i in range(0,4):
    print(listObjects[i].classList)
```

```
printed result

[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]


wanted result
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`classList` is a class attribute (i.e. shared with all instances of the class); not an instance attribute.

to get your desired behaviour your class should be:

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.classList = []


listObjects = [NewClass() for i in range(4)]

for i in range(4):
    listObjects[i].classList.append(i)
for i in range(4):
    print(listObjects[i].classList)
```

this way every instance has it's own independent `classList`.

although the name `classList` is a bit misleading now...